# CodeAttributeDeclaration - Custom attributes

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create something like that:

[MyAttribute(HelperClass.Param, ResourceType= typeof(Resources) )]
        public string Foo
        {
        }

How i can create this custom attribute?
This is piece of my code:

```
var configParamAttr = new CodeAttributeDeclaration { Name = "MyAttribute", Arguments =  new CodeAttributeArgument { Name = "ResourceType", Value = new CodePrimitiveExpression("typeof(Resources)") } } };
                currentProperty.CustomAttributes.Add(configParamAttr);
```

I don't know how I can put into custom attributes 'HelperClass.Param'. This is constant from other class. Additional my 'typeof(resources) is as string in result:

```
 [MyAttribute( ResourceType="typeof(Resources)")]
        public string Foo
        {
        }
    }
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Following code seems to work well, does it do what you want?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var a = new Foo();
        var b = new Foo2();
        var res = a.GetType().CustomAttributes;
        foreach(var i in res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        var res2 = b.GetType().CustomAttributes;
        foreach(var i in res2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}

[MyAttr(typeof(int))]
public class Foo
{
}

[MyAttr(Constants.Value,typeof(int))]
public class Foo2
{
}

public static class Constants
{
    public const int Value=1;
}

public class MyAttr:Attribute
{
    public Type Field {get;set;}

    public MyAttr(Type type)
    {
        this.Field=type;
    }
    public MyAttr(int a, Type type)
    {
        this.Field=type;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want create custom attribute like that. I want to create attribute using CodeAttributeDeclaration